# Unable to display data from json.net

Tags: json, json.net

Can anyone help solve this problem, no matter what i try i cannot display the data on webpage, i can put a breakpoints at `JObject o = JObject.Parse(ws);` and see the data, but every attempt i have tried results in a different error.I'm trying to do is get the areaName and country.

I have tried the examples from: http://james.newtonking.com/projects/json/help/  and http://forums.asp.net/t/1780822.aspx/1?How+to+traverse+in+json+ with no luck

Any help would be appreciated.
George

My code is below:

```
string ws = @"{ ""search_api"": { ""result"": [ { ""areaName"": [ {""value"": ""London"" } ],  ""country"": [ {""value"": ""United Kingdom"" } ], ""latitude"": ""51.517"", ""longitude"": ""-0.106"", ""population"": ""7421228"",  ""region"": [ {""value"": ""City Of London, Greater London"" } ],  ""timezone"": [ {""offset"": ""1.0"" } ],  ""weatherUrl"": [ {""value"": ""http:\/\/www.worldweatheronline.com\/London-weather\/City-of-London-Greater-London\/GB.aspx"" } ] }, { ""areaName"": [ {""value"": ""London"" } ],  ""country"": [ {""value"": ""Canada"" } ], ""latitude"": ""42.983"", ""longitude"": ""-81.250"", ""population"": ""346774"",  ""region"": [ {""value"": ""Ontario"" } ],  ""timezone"": [ {""offset"": ""-4.0"" } ],  ""weatherUrl"": [ {""value"": ""http:\/\/www.worldweatheronline.com\/London-weather\/Ontario\/CA.aspx"" } ] } ] }}";

       JObject o = JObject.Parse(ws);


       var weatherCity = o["areaName"][0]["value"];
       ViewBag.WeatherSearch = weatherCity.ToString();

       //var weatherCity = o["search_api"][0]["result"]["areaName"]["value"];
      // JArray arr = (JArray)o.SelectToken("search_api");
      // JObject cityTown = (JObject)arr[0].SelectToken("result").SelectToken("areaName");
     //  var weatherCity = cityTown.SelectToken("value");
       // IList<string> WeatherCity = o.SelectToken("result").Select(s => (string)s).ToList();
       //string WeatherCity = (string)o.SelectToken("result[0].areaName[0].value");
       //IList<string> WeatherCities = o["result"].Select(m => (string)m.SelectToken("areaName[0].value")).ToList();
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How about something like:

```
var weatherCity = o["search_api"]["result"][0]["areaName"][0]["value"];
```

`o` represents the root, so you can't skip any nodes.